# Paylike popup paying redirect after success payment

Tags: javascript, redirect, payment

I using Paylike.io payment solution with popupmodal. How can I redirect user after success payment? This is my code, I take javascript redirection code but don't working.

```
<script src="https://sdk.paylike.io/3.js"></script>
<script>
    var paylike = Paylike('f0301d1f-db00-4dc6-9df3-29f8822d56f6');

    function pay(){
        paylike.popup({
            currency: 'HUF',
            amount: 10000,
        }, function( err ){
            if (err)
                return console.warn(err);

            console.log(r); // { transaction: { id: ... } }

            location.href = 'payment-ok.php';
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does `I take javascript redirection code but don't working` mean? Do you get errors? If so, what errors? Saying something is not working is not enough information for someone to help you.